# Display jQuery DataTable after completely loading it

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I need to display a dataTable only after it has been completely loaded (otherwise the content "blinks" before the script finishes running).

Here is an example of what my table looks like:

HTML:

```
 <table id="dataTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First name</th>
          <th>Last name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
          <th>Extn.</th>
          <th>E-mail</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Tiger</td>
          <td>Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
          <td>5421</td>
          <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Garrett</td>
          <td>Winters</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$170,750</td>
          <td>8422</td>
          <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ashton</td>
          <td>Cox</td>
          <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2009/01/12</td>
          <td>$86,000</td>
          <td>1562</td>
          <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cedric</td>
          <td>Kelly</td>
          <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2012/03/29</td>
          <td>$433,060</td>
          <td>6224</td>
          <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Airi</td>
          <td>Satou</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>33</td>
          <td>2008/11/28</td>
          <td>$162,700</td>
          <td>5407</td>
          <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brielle</td>
          <td>Williamson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2012/12/02</td>
          <td>$372,000</td>
          <td>4804</td>
          <td>b.williamson@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Herrod</td>
          <td>Chandler</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2012/08/06</td>
          <td>$137,500</td>
          <td>9608</td>
          <td>h.chandler@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Rhona</td>
          <td>Davidson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>55</td>
          <td>2010/10/14</td>
          <td>$327,900</td>
          <td>6200</td>
          <td>r.davidson@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Colleen</td>
          <td>Hurst</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>39</td>
          <td>2009/09/15</td>
          <td>$205,500</td>
          <td>2360</td>
          <td>c.hurst@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sonya</td>
          <td>Frost</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2008/12/13</td>
          <td>$103,600</td>
          <td>1667</td>
          <td>s.frost@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jena</td>
          <td>Gaines</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2008/12/19</td>
          <td>$90,560</td>
          <td>3814</td>
          <td>j.gaines@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Quinn</td>
          <td>Flynn</td>
          <td>Support Lead</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2013/03/03</td>
          <td>$342,000</td>
          <td>9497</td>
          <td>q.flynn@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Charde</td>
          <td>Marshall</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>36</td>
          <td>2008/10/16</td>
          <td>$470,600</td>
          <td>6741</td>
          <td>c.marshall@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Haley</td>
          <td>Kennedy</td>
          <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2012/12/18</td>
          <td>$313,500</td>
          <td>3597</td>
          <td>h.kennedy@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Tatyana</td>
          <td>Fitzpatrick</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>2010/03/17</td>
          <td>$385,750</td>
          <td>1965</td>
          <td>t.fitzpatrick@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michael</td>
          <td>Silva</td>
          <td>Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2012/11/27</td>
          <td>$198,500</td>
          <td>1581</td>
          <td>m.silva@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Paul</td>
          <td>Byrd</td>
          <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2010/06/09</td>
          <td>$725,000</td>
          <td>3059</td>
          <td>p.byrd@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gloria</td>
          <td>Little</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2009/04/10</td>
          <td>$237,500</td>
          <td>1721</td>
          <td>g.little@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bradley</td>
          <td>Greer</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2012/10/13</td>
          <td>$132,000</td>
          <td>2558</td>
          <td>b.greer@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Dai</td>
          <td>Rios</td>
          <td>Personnel Lead</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>2012/09/26</td>
          <td>$217,500</td>
          <td>2290</td>
          <td>d.rios@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jenette</td>
          <td>Caldwell</td>
          <td>Development Lead</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2011/09/03</td>
          <td>$345,000</td>
          <td>1937</td>
          <td>j.caldwell@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Yuri</td>
          <td>Berry</td>
          <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>40</td>
          <td>2009/06/25</td>
          <td>$675,000</td>
          <td>6154</td>
          <td>y.berry@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Caesar</td>
          <td>Vance</td>
          <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2011/12/12</td>
          <td>$106,450</td>
          <td>8330</td>
          <td>c.vance@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Doris</td>
          <td>Wilder</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>Sidney</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2010/09/20</td>
          <td>$85,600</td>
          <td>3023</td>
          <td>d.wilder@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Angelica</td>
          <td>Ramos</td>
          <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/10/09</td>
          <td>$1,200,000</td>
          <td>5797</td>
          <td>a.ramos@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gavin</td>
          <td>Joyce</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>42</td>
          <td>2010/12/22</td>
          <td>$92,575</td>
          <td>8822</td>
          <td>g.joyce@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jennifer</td>
          <td>Chang</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>2010/11/14</td>
          <td>$357,650</td>
          <td>9239</td>
          <td>j.chang@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brenden</td>
          <td>Wagner</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>2011/06/07</td>
          <td>$206,850</td>
          <td>1314</td>
          <td>b.wagner@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Fiona</td>
          <td>Green</td>
          <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>48</td>
          <td>2010/03/11</td>
          <td>$850,000</td>
          <td>2947</td>
          <td>f.green@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Shou</td>
          <td>Itou</td>
          <td>Regional Marketing</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>2011/08/14</td>
          <td>$163,000</td>
          <td>8899</td>
          <td>s.itou@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michelle</td>
          <td>House</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Sidney</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2011/06/02</td>
          <td>$95,400</td>
          <td>2769</td>
          <td>m.house@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Suki</td>
          <td>Burks</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>53</td>
          <td>2009/10/22</td>
          <td>$114,500</td>
          <td>6832</td>
          <td>s.burks@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Prescott</td>
          <td>Bartlett</td>
          <td>Technical Author</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/05/07</td>
          <td>$145,000</td>
          <td>3606</td>
          <td>p.bartlett@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gavin</td>
          <td>Cortez</td>
          <td>Team Leader</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2008/10/26</td>
          <td>$235,500</td>
          <td>2860</td>
          <td>g.cortez@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Martena</td>
          <td>Mccray</td>
          <td>Post-Sales support</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>46</td>
          <td>2011/03/09</td>
          <td>$324,050</td>
          <td>8240</td>
          <td>m.mccray@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Unity</td>
          <td>Butler</td>
          <td>Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/12/09</td>
          <td>$85,675</td>
          <td>5384</td>
          <td>u.butler@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Howard</td>
          <td>Hatfield</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>51</td>
          <td>2008/12/16</td>
          <td>$164,500</td>
          <td>7031</td>
          <td>h.hatfield@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Hope</td>
          <td>Fuentes</td>
          <td>Secretary</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2010/02/12</td>
          <td>$109,850</td>
          <td>6318</td>
          <td>h.fuentes@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Vivian</td>
          <td>Harrell</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>62</td>
          <td>2009/02/14</td>
          <td>$452,500</td>
          <td>9422</td>
          <td>v.harrell@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Timothy</td>
          <td>Mooney</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2008/12/11</td>
          <td>$136,200</td>
          <td>7580</td>
          <td>t.mooney@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jackson</td>
          <td>Bradshaw</td>
          <td>Director</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>65</td>
          <td>2008/09/26</td>
          <td>$645,750</td>
          <td>1042</td>
          <td>j.bradshaw@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Olivia</td>
          <td>Liang</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2011/02/03</td>
          <td>$234,500</td>
          <td>2120</td>
          <td>o.liang@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bruno</td>
          <td>Nash</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>38</td>
          <td>2011/05/03</td>
          <td>$163,500</td>
          <td>6222</td>
          <td>b.nash@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sakura</td>
          <td>Yamamoto</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2009/08/19</td>
          <td>$139,575</td>
          <td>9383</td>
          <td>s.yamamoto@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Thor</td>
          <td>Walton</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2013/08/11</td>
          <td>$98,540</td>
          <td>8327</td>
          <td>t.walton@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Finn</td>
          <td>Camacho</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/07/07</td>
          <td>$87,500</td>
          <td>2927</td>
          <td>f.camacho@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Serge</td>
          <td>Baldwin</td>
          <td>Data Coordinator</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2012/04/09</td>
          <td>$138,575</td>
          <td>8352</td>
          <td>s.baldwin@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zenaida</td>
          <td>Frank</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2010/01/04</td>
          <td>$125,250</td>
          <td>7439</td>
          <td>z.frank@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zorita</td>
          <td>Serrano</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>56</td>
          <td>2012/06/01</td>
          <td>$115,000</td>
          <td>4389</td>
          <td>z.serrano@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jennifer</td>
          <td>Acosta</td>
          <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2013/02/01</td>
          <td>$75,650</td>
          <td>3431</td>
          <td>j.acosta@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cara</td>
          <td>Stevens</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>46</td>
          <td>2011/12/06</td>
          <td>$145,600</td>
          <td>3990</td>
          <td>c.stevens@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Hermione</td>
          <td>Butler</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2011/03/21</td>
          <td>$356,250</td>
          <td>1016</td>
          <td>h.butler@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lael</td>
          <td>Greer</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2009/02/27</td>
          <td>$103,500</td>
          <td>6733</td>
          <td>l.greer@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jonas</td>
          <td>Alexander</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2010/07/14</td>
          <td>$86,500</td>
          <td>8196</td>
          <td>j.alexander@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Shad</td>
          <td>Decker</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>51</td>
          <td>2008/11/13</td>
          <td>$183,000</td>
          <td>6373</td>
          <td>s.decker@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Michael</td>
          <td>Bruce</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>2011/06/27</td>
          <td>$183,000</td>
          <td>5384</td>
          <td>m.bruce@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Donna</td>
          <td>Snider</td>
          <td>Customer Support</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/01/25</td>
          <td>$112,000</td>
          <td>4226</td>
          <td>d.snider@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTable').DataTable( {
        "scrollY": '50vh',
        "scrollX": true
    } );
} );
```

CSS:

```
div.dataTables_wrapper {
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 400px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/scdtbry5/2/

And the straight-forward solution was nesting the table into a hidden container. After the dataTable scrip has ended I execute a fadeIn to display the container:

http://jsfiddle.net/2d73wt5L/29/

Usually this technique works for me, but the problem here is that, after fading in , all column headers show up completely broken. However, if I click any toggle inside the dataTable (sort, next page etc), the headers properly align with the cells underneath them. I'd like the table to fade in like that.

Comment: When you are displaying it you can use its [columns.adjust()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust()) api function, which will adjust the columns width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you can use its [columns.adjust()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust()) api function which adjusts the columns width of datatable after datatable is displayed.

### columns.adjust()

Recalculate the column widths.

> Like HTML tables, DataTables attempts to layout tables in an optimal format based on the data in the cells. As the data changes, it can sometimes be useful to recalculate this layout. Additionally DataTables makes extensive use of the dimensions of DOM elements in the table which scrolling is enabled (to align the columns) so if a table is hidden when initialised the height / width of the table elements will be unavailable.
>
> This method is provided to have DataTables recalculate the columns sizes, based on the data in the table and the size applied to the columns (in the DOM, CSS or through the columns.width parameter). Call it when the table becomes visible if hidden when initialised (for example in a tab) or when the data changes significantly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTable').DataTable( {
        "scrollY": '50vh',
        "scrollX": true
    } );
    $('#hidden').fadeIn();
    $('#dataTable').DataTable().columns.adjust().draw();
} );
```

**Demo**

Forked JsFiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/f8bds4om/

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround!

Instead of using **display: none;** and **.fadeIn(300);** I used **opacity : 0;** and .**fadeTo(300, 1);**

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTable').DataTable( {
        "scrollY": '50vh',
        "scrollX": true
    } );
    $('#hidden').fadeTo(300,1);
} );
```

CSS:

```
div.dataTables_wrapper {
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 400px;
}

div#hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2d73wt5L/31/

It seems that DataTable doesn't work properly with elements that are not displayed. If anyone can come up with an explanation I'll gladly accept it.